# Несовместимые завершения строк

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

`VS15` периодически выдаёт окно

> Несовместимые завершения строк
>
> Завершения строк в следующем файле не являются единообразными.
>   Нормализовать завершение строк?

Что это означает? Если нормализовать, то через какое-то время в другом файле появляется то же самое.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Строки в текстовом файле нужно как то разделять. И для этого в мире придумали [три основных способа](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8):

- **LF** (ASCII 0x0A) используется в Multics, UNIX, UNIX-подобных операционных системах (GNU/Linux, AIX, Xenix, Mac OS X, FreeBSD и др.), BeOS, Amiga UNIX, RISC OS и других;
- **CR** (ASCII 0x0D) используется в 8-битовых машинах Commodore, машинах TRS-80, Apple II, системах Mac OS до версии 9 и OS-9;
- **CR+LF** (ASCII 0x0D 0x0A) используется в DEC RT-11 и большинстве других ранних не-UNIX- и не-IBM-систем, а также в CP/M, MP/M (англ.), MS-DOS, OS/2, Microsoft Windows, Symbian OS, протоколах Интернет.

И разные редакторы по разному относятся к разным переводам строк. К примеру, виндовый notepad не понимает LF переводы и показывает весь текст в одну строку.

Но бывает ситуация и хуже - смесь различных переводов строк в одном файле. В этом случае бывают "чудеса". К примеру, старые компиляторы делфи не корректно считали номер строки в этом случае и иногда могли показывать строку с ошибкой в другом месте (выше, чем она есть на самом деле), но при этом редактор показывал текст корректно.

Редактор студии знает о этой проблеме и заведомо предупреждает. **Если Вы работаете только в винде и только студийным компилятором, то следует использовать CR+LF. Он естественен для винды.**

Почему же так происходит, что в файле оказываются смешанные переводы строк?

Самый простой способ - используется сторонний редактор, в котором неверно выставлены перевод строк. И достаточно добавить таким редактором строку-другую, как проблема появиться.

Другой способ получит такую проблему - неверно настроенный git. Дело в том, что git, являясь изначально утилитой с мира Linux, использует LF для перевода строк. Но когда его портировали в видновс, с этим возникли проблемы. Поэтому сделали хак - гит умеет автоматически переконвертировать - то есть, в репозитории хранится с LF,  а при checkout конвертирует в нужные. Хорошая [статья на эту тему](http://jenyay.net/Git/Autocrlf).